# Magento 1.9.4.3 order grid filter error

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, order-grid

We use the following module to load the SKU inside the order grid in the backend. https://github.com/vovsky/ExtendedGrid/

This worked perfectly before we updated to the latest Magento 1.9.4.3. When using the filter, we get the following error:

Any ideas how to solve this?

```
a:5:{i:0;s:444:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'skus' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.entity_id) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `address` ON main_table.entity_id = address.parent_id AND address.address_type = "shipping"
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` ON `sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id WHERE (`skus` LIKE '%20R90074MH%')";i:1;s:6462:"#0 /lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
#4 /lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
#5 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
#6 /lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(225): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(225): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
#8 /lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(211): Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
#9 /lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(522): Varien_Data_Collection->getCurPage()
#10 /lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(569): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_renderLimit()
#11 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(550): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#12 /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php(62): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#13 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(643): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#14 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(649): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#15 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(922): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#16 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#18 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#19 /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#20 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/domains/re...')
#21 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#22 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#23 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#24 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#26 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#28 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(641): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(585): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#30 /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#31 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/domains/re...')
#32 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#33 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#34 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#35 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(923): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#36 /app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#37 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#38 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(95): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#39 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->indexAction()
#40 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#41 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#42 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(381): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#43 /app/Mage.php(686): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#44 /index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#45 {main}";s:3:"url";s:73:"/index.php/admin/sales_order/index/key/b08f6bd15a52b15f92423f70d52a36fe/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/292307/4087

Comment: @BlueC Thanks! But I can not solve the issue for this module. Any idea what class should be changed to make it work?